# Entity Framework 6 Code First: specific model design implementation

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a little model but i have a doubt on how to design.

My idea is to have three classes: JobReport/Customer/Project.
The scope is to populate reports choosing Customer and then Project that is bound to its customer (plus other payloads).

My design is:

[image: Design 1]

MODEL:

```
public class EFDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<JobReport> JobReport { get; set; }
}
```

When i scaffold JobReport View and use its model i find difficoult to bind Customer entity, since it is directly bound to Project and not to JobReport.
Another solution is to put both CustomerID and ProjectID into JobReport, but it seems to me it's redundant.

[image: Design 2]

I have in my mind two possibilities:
1- keep the first model and create a ViewModel with JobReport and Customer separately
2- Use the second model so i have all the IDs.

What do you think about it? 
How would you implement this case?

Thanks very much!!

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of observations:

- Design 1 seems appropriate, unless one JobReport should be able to reference multiple projects belonging to different customers.
- The ProjectID property doesn't belong in the Customer type, right? The Projects collection is rightfully there, though.
- The Project type should have a JobReports collection that lists all reports belonging to a specific object.

This is a problem that is closely related to discussions about identifying aggregates in Domain Driven Design. It seems that your Customer entity is a natural aggregate root, which means that all interactions with objects inside the aggregate must go through the customer.

This would mean that the DbContext should look like this instead:

```
public class EFDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

And to get sub-items belonging to a customer, you use LINQ to traverse the relations:

```
public IEnumerable<JobReport> GetReportsByCustomer(int customerId)
{
    using (var context = new EFDBContext())
    {
        return context.Customers.Where(x => x.CustomerID.Equals(customerId))
            .SelectMany(x => x.Projects)
            .SelectMany(x => x.JobReports)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp);
    }
}
```

You can also select to always use the Customer as base for your edit actions, since it's the aggregate root. This would involve pulling the Customer out of the database and make sure that all detail data is included:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomer(int customerId)
{
    using (var context = new EFDBContext())
    {
        return context.Customers
            .Include(x => x.Projects.Select(y => y.JobReports))
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerID.Equals(customerId));
    }
}
```

You would need to manually add `using System.Data.Entity;` at the top of your class file for the above code to work.

Comment: your observations are right. My doubt was to decide if to bend Customer with JobReport or (rightfully) not. You remove my doubts. Thanks!!

Comment: And what about if i want to validate the customer in Razor something like this?     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

Comment: Then it seems that you're acting on the customer entity and not only the job reports. See my updated answer to learn how you can get access to both the customer data and its detail data.